# rivets.js custom binders arguments

Tags: javascript, html, rickshaw, rivets.js

I just stated with rivets.js binders and have a simple problem. In my html file I've got a custom binder like `<div rv-dashing-graph="mydata"></div>` which returns the value of "mydata" to my binder.

In this I'm using it to set properties to this value:

```
rivets.binders['dashing-graph'] = function binder(el, data) {
if (!data) return;
// ...
if (/rickshaw_graph/.test(container.className)) {
    graph = window[container.dataset.id];
    graph.series[0].data = data;
    graph.update();
    return;
}

graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
    element: container,
    width: container.width,
    height: container.height,
    series: [{
        color: '#fff', //white
        data: data
    }, ]
});
```

My problem is now that I'd like to have two data series in my Rickshaw graph, which is why I'd like to do something like

```
series: [{
                data: data, //the value of myData
                color: '#dfea34' 
        }, {
                data: data2, //value of second variable
                color: '#000' 
        }]
```

But how do I parse 2 values in my binder, so I can access "mydata" and "mysecondData" in the html file, but more specifically, how does the binder get that I want to have two variables?

Comment: I've removed the irrelevant tag [tag:binder] and added the relevant tag [tag:rivets.js]. Please be sure to read the description of a tag before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the entire `series` array to the binder like

```
<div rv-dashing-graph="series"></div>
```

You can iterate an access each objects inside it in the binder.

Comment: "series" is a special rickshaw attribute, wicht lets me draw 2 graphs in one picture. I can only pass the mydata element from my python class like `"mydata = [
        {'x':0,   "y":50 },
        {"x":5,   "y":10},
        {"x": 10, "y": 50},
    ]" `

Comment: i cannot parse the wohle series element because i need to work with the data field in javaskript as well (data says for example how big the graph is supposed to be).

Comment: i just need a way to figure out, how to parse 2 elements in a custom binder, so that i can acces both. (in best case with two variables like `function binder(el, data, data2) `, but even one array with two fields would help me a lot!

Comment: @LUIGI Then it's not a question about rivets binder. You just need to find a way to put your 2 data objects in an array...?

Comment: How to parse an array in binders, and more specifically how to acces the array in the binder is what i cannot figure out :(